# Bicep Linter suppress Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors

Tags: lint, azure-bicep

[GitHub discussion](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/8508) on this same topic.

Was wondering if something like this could be used to suppress issues that are found in inner modules we want tobut it does not appear to suppress the error.

```
#disable-next-line use-recent-api-versions
module moduleWeDependOn 'dependencies/module.bicep' = if (param) { // other implemenation details }
// even with the suppression comment the linter still throws errors, if i add the suppression line to dependencies/module.bicep directly, the error is suppressed.
```

Is there a way to suppress this bicep linter error? It appears in many instances of our builds, but we preferably would like to ignore this.

```bash
file.bicep(3,46) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(1,45) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(7,52) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(3,53) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(9,47) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(9,45) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(4,50) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(9,57) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
file.bicep(4,55) : Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.
```

Using a similar linter config

```json
{
    "analyzers": {
        "core": {
            "enabled": true,
            "verbose": false,
            "rules": {
                "adminusername-should-not-be-literal": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "artifacts-parameters": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "explicit-values-for-loc-params": {
                    "level": "error"
                },                
                "no-hardcoded-env-urls": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "no-hardcoded-location": {
                    "level": "error"
                },                
                "no-unnecessary-dependson": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "no-loc-expr-outside-params": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "no-unused-existing-resources": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "no-unused-params": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "no-unused-vars": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "max-outputs": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "max-params": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "max-resources": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "max-variables": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "outputs-should-not-contain-secrets": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "prefer-interpolation": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "protect-commandtoexecute-secrets": {
                    "level": "error"
                },                
                "prefer-unquoted-property-names": {
                    "level": "error"
                },                
                "use-stable-vm-image": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "use-recent-api-versions": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "use-resource-id-functions": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "use-stable-resource-identifiers": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "secure-parameter-default": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "secure-params-in-nested-deploy": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "secure-secrets-in-params": {
                    "level": "error"
                },
                "simplify-interpolation": {
                    "level": "error"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not sure to understand. In your linter configuration, you define these rules as errors but you would like to ignore them ? You can change the linter configuration to set the level to `Off` if you d like to supress the error or disble the linter.

Comment: I want to oppress the `Error BCP104: The referenced module has errors.` message, is there a way to do that in this JSON config?

Comment: If you check your module, what is the inner error ? Some errors are real error and can't be suppressed

Comment: `use-recent-api-versions` @Thomas but really I want to do is this
```bicep
#disable-next-line use-recent-api-versions
module moduleWeDependOn 'dependencies/module.bicep' = if (param) { // other implemenation details }
```

Comment: but then you defined `use-recent-api-versions` as an error in the linter, you can just set this setting to off.